# How to use `.each()` to iterate rows in a table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

I have a table which I added the rows dynamically. Each row has unique ID and a checkbox. Now I need to constantly check through each added row to see if the checkbox for each row is checked. If they are checked, the information on that row should be collected to post to a python function.

Any hints on how should I go about doing it? I have tried a few but they don't seem to work. Looks like my way of solving may be wrong.

EDIT: Here's my trial code: http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/jsXWe/
it just won't append what I want in div #test

```
$('#status_table tr').each(function(){
    $check=$('#status_table #monitor_'+rowID)
    if ($check.is(':checked')){
         monitoring(rowID);
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your html and javascript code plz.

Comment: Please add the html code for your HTML and your current jquery code else you won't get a precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mytable tr input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
   //inside this callback, 'this' will refer to a selected node (a checkbox)
   if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
       ....
   }
})
```

Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsXWe/1/)

Comment: thanks! i did that before except 'input[type="checkbox"]'but i just tried that, not working too :( (i've added my fiddle above)

Comment: umm no. if you select something and click "add", there will be checkboxes. Their states are what i want.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to debug your code. As a general remark : if your fiddle needs a man page, it is not a good way to illustrate your problem. The `each` loop by itself works fine (see the example). Your problem resides elsewhere.

Comment: thank you but your fiddle doesn't seem to alert when i check the box? :s

Comment: Oh anyway, thank you! i think i realize one important issue - each() will in my code will only be called once! that's why if there is no preset checked checkbox, it will not display anything!am i right?